# Writing a recursive string reverser what is my smaller input?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

My exercise says I need to write a recursive function to reverse a given string, using this prototype:
`void reverse(char s[]);`

The only pre-written function I'm allowed to use is `strlen()` from `string.h` library.

I have no clue where to begin from.

Comment: Also, is this in c or c++?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I simply don't know where to start from, this looks like none of the recursions I know

Comment: Start by creating an empty `main` method with a `void reverse(char s[]);` function above it.  Then look into `for` loops.

Comment: This I already have, all but the `for` loop you were talking about.

Comment: Cool, so start by using a `for` loop to iterate over the array `s`. A hint is that `stringlen()` will give you the size of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by having your function call another function that performs the actual recursion:

This might be more familiar recursive signature:

```
void reverse(char s[]) 
{
    reverse_helper(s,strlen(s));
}

void reverse_helper(char s[], int position) 
{
 // actual recursive code goes here
}
```

---

Since you cannot use helper functions:

This is homework and it sounds like you do not just want the answer so ask yourself the following questions.

What is your base case?

> strlent(s) <= 1 // no reversing needed 
>  at strlen(s) == 2, we need a trivial reversal with no recursion.

We know that reversing a 2 length char array is trivial, but how do you reverse a 3 length char array?

> take the last char from the 3 length array and place it at the front of the reversed 2 length array.

What do a pass to my recusive calls of `reverse`?

> a new char array that is one size smaller.

Comment: But this means that reverse() isn't recursive and this is not what I was asked to do

Comment: @Eran, fair enough, does my edit answer any of your 'I do not know where to start' questions?

Comment: `strlen = 1` means only `\0` is in the array right? so my trivial reverse should be `strlen = 3`

Comment: no, `strlen()` returns the number of characters that preceed the null character. http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/string.h/strlen.php

Comment: right, also you're suggesting using an auxiliary array, but I can't set it's `MAX_SIZE` since my function should work with any given input.

Comment: I've asked my friend to help me and he said the only possible way to solve this question and write this program is with using array pointers, is that true? I am not sure I am allowed to use pointers since I never learned about them in lectures.

Comment: @Eran, pointers will make it easier, but creating a new char[], passing it to reverse(), and then copying the entries from the result should have the same effect.

Comment: How could you possibly create a new char[] without knowing up front what is the input size?

Comment: `char[strlen(s)]`: `strlen(s)-1` for the chars needing reversal. 1 for the null char. Comments are not intended for extended discussions, if you have further questions, please post a new question.

Comment: declaring an array with a variable is not possible mate.

Comment: @Eran, it was a generalization. Use malloc or make the auxillary array of whatever MAX_SIZE you think will work and just place the '\0' at position strlen(s).